# Generalized eigenvectors as basis of dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional vector space over some field K. Let $A$ be an endomorphism over $V$, and let $A^*$ be an endomorphism over $V^*$ (the dual space of $V$).

If $V$ has a basis consisting of generalized eigenvectors of $A$, does $V^*$ then have a basis consisting of generalized eigenvectors of $A^*$?

I know the statement holds, if we just talking eigenvectors, and from the proof, I have a feeling, that it doesn't hold for generalized eigenvectors, however I'm not really convinced. Why doesn't/does it hold?

All the simple examples I've tries to look into, seems to not give a counterexample.

Comment: The answer is yes. In short: using a basis $\mathcal B$ of $V$ for which the matrix of $A$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is the Jordan form of $A$, it is straightforward to find a construct a basis $\mathcal B^*$ of $V^*$ for which the matrix of $A^*$ relative to $\mathcal B^*$ is in Jordan form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that if an endomorphism $A$ has the representation matrix $M$ with respect to some bases then the dual endomorphism $A^*$ has the representation matrix $M^t$, the transpose matrix with respect to the dual bases.

If $A$ now has a basis of generealized eigenvectors this is equivalent to saying that the representation matrix $M$ has a jordan normal form. But for any matrix, $M$ and $M^t$ are similar so that $M^t$ is similar to the jordan normal form of $M$, i.e. it also has a jordan normal form. Hence the endomorphism it represents, namely $A^*$ has a basis of generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Does $A$ always have a Jordan normal form? Wouldn't we need $K$ to be algebraically closed?

Comment: For any $A$ to have a Jordan normal form you are right, we would need $K$ to be algebraically closed. But in your problem the assumption was that $A$ has a basis of generalized eigenvectors and this is equivalent to having a Jordan normal form. So for the specific problem you presented we don't need $K$ to be algebraically closed.